# ficheiro txt inseri na bd

Tags: php, mysqli, txt

boas, estou a fazer um website, em que vai buscar um ficheiro txt que o utilizador vai dar upload(sempre no msm formato(processo, nome,numero)). Ando a tentar utilizar arrays buscar os dados e inserir na base de dados. ja consegui ir buscar mas nao consigo por na array os dados. por exemplo, tenho no ficheiro txt esta linha(12345. andre,1)e quero que a array fique array 1 = 12345, array 2 = andre e array 1, para fazer um ciclo para inserir os alunos todos na bd.

Ja experimentei varios codigos e nao cheguei a lado nenhum, este foi o ultimo que tentei;
include("includes\ligacaobd.php");
$arquivo=('alunos.txt');
$separador = "  "; // O que separa os resultados no arquivos TXT ?

```
if(file_exists($arquivo)){
  $fp=fopen($arquivo,'r');
  while(!feof($fp)){
    $line = trim(fgets($fp));
    if (empty($line)) {
     continue;
    }
    $lines = rtrim($line, ';'); //remover o ';' que tens no fim de cada linha
    $array = explode($separador, $lines); //separar por $separador

    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO aluno (numero, nome, processo) VALUES ('" . $array[0] . "', '" . @$array[1] . "', '" . @$array[2] . "')";
    $resultado1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

    if(!$resultado1){
     print "Falha na linha: " . $line;
    }
  }
  fclose($fp);

  print "Terminado";
}
```

podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo simples para que tenha uma idéia melhor de como fazer:

```
$data = file('tmp.txt'); // aqui vc coloca o caminho completo do arquivo txt.
// A função file() faz a leitura do arquivo e retorna cada linha num array.

// Monta a query SQL
// Será gerado um único INSERT com múltiplos valores.
// Dessa forma economizará invocando mysqli_query() apenas uma vez.
$query = 'INSERT INTO aluno (numero, nome, processo) VALUES ';
foreach ($data as $v) {
    $arr = explode(',', trim($v));
    $query .= PHP_EOL.'(\''.$arr[0].'\', \''.$arr[1].'\', \''.$arr[2].'\')';
}
$query .= ';';

// Teste para exibir na tela como foi gerada a query.
// Verifique se foi montado corretamente e então prossiga com o restante.
echo $query; exit;

// Considerando que $conn está com uma conexão ativa e tudo correto, então segue com a execução da query sql gerada acima
//$resultado1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

**obs**: no código original da pergunta percebi esse trecho

```
 @$array[1] . "', '" . @$array[2]
```

Está usando inibidor de erro porque esses índices podem ser inexistentes?

Independente da resposta, preferi omitir algum tratamento nos valores obtidos do array pois na descrição da pergunta não informa com detalhes quais as regras do negócio. Portanto, esteja ciente de que precisa fazer tratamentos dos dados antes de montar a query e principalmente antes de enviá-la para execução.